# To zip file using windows bat script

Tags: batch-file

I have situation to zip files coming in the folder. For example, files are present in folder

```
D:/Source
SOURCE_FILES_TEST_111.TXT
SOURCE_FILES_TEST_222.TXT
```

I need to have a script to zip these files so that result will be zipped in same folder.

```
D:/Source
SOURCE_FILES_TEST_111.ZIP
SOURCE_FILES_TEST_222.ZIP.
```

I am new to scripting, can any one help to create the entire script to execute this?

Comment: how would you do it manually?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.computerhope.com/forum/index.php?topic=48650.0

Probably this can be of some help